# How do I Reference all non-blank cells after row A6 for a Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I want to use the following formula: 
`INDEX(A6:A94,MODE(MATCH(A6:A94,A6:A94,0)))`

Except the exact number of rows is ambiguous (imported using VBA). 
How can I reference all non-blank cells starting from A6 to be used in the formula above?

It should be something like this: `INDEX(A6:A{last non blank},MODE(MATCH(A6:A{last non blank},A6:A{last non blank},0)))`

Thank you!

Comment: It's important to try to solve the problem on your own. A quick google search for "excel last non-blank cell" yields a solution from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5441885/4475014).

Comment: I wish it were that easy, but it is a bit more complicated than that. I am looking for a compact reference A6:A{last non blank}.

Comment: I need to use it in a formula and cant quite figure that out. I've searched google for quite a while

Comment: I haven't tested this but this may work: 
"INDEX(A6:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A)),MODE(MATCH(A6:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A)),A6:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A)),0)))"

Comment: You can also use a named range and make the range dynamic.  The formula for a dynamic range looks something like this: "=OFFSET(SheetName!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(SheetName!$A:$A),1)" then use the named range in the formula.  You can drop the SheetName! part if the formula is on the same sheet.

Comment: Has this question been moved from StackOverflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874261/simple-enquiry-with-complex-answer-how-do-i-select-rowa6-rowlast-non-blank-f/30876467#30876467 Or have you simply duplicated it here also?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to reference a range of variable size. There are also several ways to find the last non-blank in a column.

---

First, how to find the row with the last non-blank in column `A:A`:

I'm going to wrap these formulas in an `IFERROR` statement that will return `6` if it errors out. This is because you state that your data starts at row 6 so, if something goes wrong, this will let you return just `A6` instead of some error message. If you *want* an error to show, then just remove the `IFERROR` wrapping.

If your data is all numbers, use this: `IFERROR(MATCH(10^308,A:A),6)`
If your data is all text, use this: `IFERROR(MATCH(REPT(CHAR(255),255),A:A),6)`
If your data is numbers and text, then find the max value of the two: `MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(10^308,A:A),6),IFERROR(MATCH(REPT(CHAR(255),255),A:A),6)`

You can also use an array formula but I tend to stay away from those because they're typically slower. It would be as shown below and would be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. (You'll know it's right if curly brackets { } appear on either side of the formula.)

```
MAX(ROW(A:A)*NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))
```

---

Second, how to reference the range `A6:A{last non blank row}`:

Since you want the same reference three times, it might be a good idea to add a helper cell. There are multiple ways to get at what we want but I'm going to show a few. Let's say that the helper cell is `B1` and the formula you want is in `B2`. I'm just going to use the "last row" example formula for text because I believe that's what you're data is. You should change it to whatever you need.

The `INDEX` method: (probably the best option)

```
B1 = IFERROR(MATCH(REPT(CHAR(255),255),A:A),6)
B2 = INDEX(A6:INDEX(A:A,B1),MODE(MATCH(A6:INDEX(A:A,B1),A6:INDEX(A:A,B1),0)))
```

The `INDIRECT` method:

```
B1 = "A6:A"&IFERROR(MATCH(REPT(CHAR(255),255),A:A),6)
B2 = INDEX(INDIRECT(B1),MODE(MATCH(INDIRECT(B1),INDIRECT(B1),0)))
```

The `OFFSET` method:

```
B1 = IFERROR(MATCH(REPT(CHAR(255),255),A:A),6)
B2 =INDEX(OFFSET(A6,0,0,B1-5),MODE(MATCH(OFFSET(A6,0,0,B1-5),OFFSET(A6,0,0,B1-5),0)))
```

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Comment: Neither of the volatile INDIRECT or OFFSET approaches is necessary. A simple INDEX construction is much preferable for creating the dynamic range. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874261/simple-enquiry-with-complex-answer-how-do-i-select-rowa6-rowlast-non-blank-f/30876467#30876467

Comment: @XORLX I have never used `INDIRECT` in its reference form and, quite frankly, didn't realize it had one. This could be very useful. I'll update accordingly. Thanks.